# Using user's liked media in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, instagram

On my website, I display a list of media from a specific tag. When the user is authenticated I would like to visually mark the media that he has voted on.

Currently, the list I'm displaying is read from my own database. I have a synchronizing process that subscribes to the tag. When I get these values from the /tags/tag-name/media/recent end point, I am not authenticated as any user.

The way I had planned to do this is that when a user logs in to my website, I hit the  `/users/self/media/liked` end point and store them in session (running c# / MVC4). But I'm looking at the `JSON` result from that endpoint and it's a complete "Medias response" type with paging and everything. Basically at 20 per page, if a user has liked some 250 media, logging in would require 24 API calls and would take too long.

How do you handle this issue?

I could save the them to database...

I could save the complete list of liking users as I synchronize my media...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the user is authenticated and then if you make the recent tag API call `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` with the user's access_token, then the JSON response will have a **`"user_has_liked"`** element, this will be `true` if the user has liked the picture and `false` if not.

You can use this data to display if user have liked or not from a list of tag media. You dont have to get all user liked media and compare, instagram tag media API already has this information if you use the user's access_token to make tag media call.

Comment: currently I'm not displaying media from the Instagram API. I've offloaded them to my own database. The reason for this is that I expect more than 5k queries per hour and most users will not be authenticated.Thanks!